# Microsoft SSTP VPN returning HTTP 503

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, sstp

So I have finally set up my certificates correctly and such, so I'm trying to connect to my VPN. The Windows client is giving me an error with the code "0x800704D4".  I looked into it and was told to visit a [URL](https://FQDN/sra_%7BBA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75%7D/), which I did, replacing the FQDN with my own.  I'm getting a page saying that there is an 503 Service Unavailable error.

Any idea how I can fix this so I can finally get my VPN set up?

Answer (score 1):

See Microsoft [KB947026](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947026) and [RRAS Event ID 24](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733844.aspx) for detailed steps to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause of this error is when the hostname of the VPN server is not resolved by the forward proxy in-front of the VPN client. 0x800704D4 means The network connection was aborted by the local system.Possible solutions could be to check your proxy settings inside the Internet explorer. If the settings are correct, please ensure you are able to access other web sites (e.g. www.microsoft.com) using the browser. If that also works through, try accessing the URI which SSTP uses internally i.e. https://vpn_server_name/sra_{BA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75}/  -  please replace vpn_server_name with actual VPN server name. If you see error “the website cannot be found” inside your browser, that validates the hostname resolution failure. If you know the IP address of VPN server, try connecting with that. Else contact your network administrator (who is responsible for managing the web proxy – most probably your ISP) – giving them the details of the problem (i.e. hostname resolution is failing for that particular hostname). Also if possible check the Event Logs of RRAS server

Comment: Well, I don't use a proxy to connect to the internet. I can view other web pages correctly as well as the VPN server, both through its DNS name and IP address.

Comment: Does this help: [Debugging SSTP error -2147023660](http://msmvps.com/blogs/alunj/archive/2009/01/28/1666579.aspx)? Are your certificates configured for 0.0.0.0:Port for IPv4, and [::]:Port for IPv6?

Comment: Certificates are all configured.  So far it seems to be that the client can't get an IP address from the server. Take a look at this thread that I have on the Technet forum. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverNIS/thread/953626cd-5117-4cdc-b7e3-1f1524657070/

Comment: Maybe run a network capture with Netmon, to see where the communication hangs? For the rest I'm out of ideas, maybe open a support case at Microsoft? And with a VPN is a best practice to have two network adapters.

Comment: From where should I run Netmon, the client?

Comment: To get the best overview I would advice to take a capture both on the client side and on the server side.